# Opencv build do not set tbb as ON

Tags: unix, opencv, build, cmake, tbb

I have downloaded latest source of tbb and run the following commands (working on raspbian):

```
sudo make CXXFLAGS="-DTBB_USE_GCC_BUILTINS=1 -D__TBB_64BIT_ATOMICS=0"
source tbbvars.sh (in the related folder)
```

but when I do

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON
```

it do not actually set TBB:ON. So I do not continue with make, make install. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it takes [much work](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2007/09/09/globalized-tbb-environment-configuration-on-linux) to make tbb visible

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_TBB=ON ..
```

just does the trick. Hope this will help other beginners as well.